# Get active processes through Java on Windows 2000 Pro

Tags: java, windows-server-2000, tasklist

I want to get the name of all active process on a Win2000 machine. I know that "tlist -s" is the command, but to use this, the "tlist.exe" has to be extracted from the Win2000 CD-ROM. I also know "tasklist" only works on XP or greater.

I am running my tests on VM Ware, and do not have a CD-ROM. Is there another way to programmatically get the task list on Win2000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just using JNI to handle this case across all platforms that I needed. Refer to another post of mine (which was trying to use SWT to obtain this list, but it gives a good JNI downloadable example that is useful):

[Get task manager list via SWT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347732/get-task-manager-list-via-swt)

Answer (score 0):

In Java without calling a 3rd party application (like say [PsList](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896682.aspx))? Not without JNI.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The more I looked online the more I was thinking there is no other way (except 3rd party).